# Calling forEach on a stream causes java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, java-stream, illegalstateexception

I have a program which does the following:

1. Stores a file name in Main method
2. Passes that file to the below method(StreamParser)from Main
3. Method StreamParser reads that file as Stream
4. StreamParser should return Stream
5. In main method when I call forEach on purchaseEventStream it gives an error in line

   purchaseEventStream.forEach(purchaseEvent -> {

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: source already consumed or 
    closed
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.sourceSpliterator(AbstractPipeline.java:409)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at com.cognitree.internship.streamprocessing.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

StreamParser Class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StreamParser {

public Stream<PurchaseEvent> parser(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Stream<PurchaseEvent> purchaseEventStream;
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        purchaseEventStream= lines.map(line -> {
            String[] fields = line.split(",");
            PurchaseEvent finalPurchaseEvent = new PurchaseEvent();
            finalPurchaseEvent.setSessionId(fields[0]);
            finalPurchaseEvent.setTimeStamp(fields[1]);
            finalPurchaseEvent.setItemId(fields[2]);
            finalPurchaseEvent.setPrice(fields[3]);
            finalPurchaseEvent.setQuantity(fields[4]);
            return finalPurchaseEvent;
        });
        return purchaseEventStream;
    }
}
}
```

Main Class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(new 
    FileOutputStream("output1.txt"));
    String file = "/Users/mohit/intern-mohit/yoochoose-buys.dat";
    StreamParser streamParser = new StreamParser();
    List<ReportGenerator> reports = new ArrayList<>();
    PurchaseEventCount purchaseEventCount = new PurchaseEventCount();
    QuantityPerSession quantityPerSession = new QuantityPerSession();
    SessionCount sessionCount = new SessionCount();
    reports.add(purchaseEventCount);
    reports.add(sessionCount);
    reports.add(quantityPerSession);
    Stream<PurchaseEvent> purchaseEventStream = streamParser.parser(file);
    purchaseEventStream.forEach(purchaseEvent -> {
        for (ReportGenerator report : reports) {
            report.generateReports(purchaseEvent);
        }
    });
    reports.forEach(report -> {
        try {
            report.printReports(outputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Why am i getting the error?

Comment: I suggest you read how to write a [mcve]. The code in your question is not a reproducible example. Classes `PurchaseEvent`, `ReportGenerator`, `PurchaseEventCount`, `QuantityPerSession` and `SessionCount` are not needed in order to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A stream in java is not a collection. It does not store data. You should create and return a collection from method `parser()` in class `StreamParser` and then create a stream from the returned collection.

I rewrote your `StreamParser` class to return a `List`.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamParser {

    public List<PurchaseEvent> parser(String fileName) throws IOException {
        List<PurchaseEvent> purchaseEventStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
                                                       .map(line -> {
                                                           String[] fields = line.split(",");
                                                           PurchaseEvent finalPurchaseEvent = new PurchaseEvent();
                                                           finalPurchaseEvent.setSessionId(fields[0]);
                                                           finalPurchaseEvent.setTimeStamp(fields[1]);
                                                           finalPurchaseEvent.setItemId(fields[2]);
                                                           finalPurchaseEvent.setPrice(fields[3]);
                                                           finalPurchaseEvent.setQuantity(fields[4]);
                                                           return finalPurchaseEvent;
                                                       })
                                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return purchaseEventStream;
    }
}
```

And I changed your `Main` class accordingly.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output1.txt"));
        String file = "/Users/mohit/intern-mohit/yoochoose-buys.dat";
        StreamParser streamParser = new StreamParser();
        List<ReportGenerator> reports = new ArrayList<>();
        PurchaseEventCount purchaseEventCount = new PurchaseEventCount();
        QuantityPerSession quantityPerSession = new QuantityPerSession();
        SessionCount sessionCount = new SessionCount();
        reports.add(purchaseEventCount);
        reports.add(sessionCount);
        reports.add(quantityPerSession);
        List<PurchaseEvent> purchaseEventStream = streamParser.parser(file);
        purchaseEventStream.forEach(purchaseEvent -> {
            for (ReportGenerator report : reports) {
                report.generateReports(purchaseEvent);
            }
        });
        reports.forEach(report -> {
            try {
                report.printReports(outputStream);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```